# Accessing Public Web API

Tags: javascript, api, cors, asp.net-web-api

Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction, I have searched for days but still nothing. I'm trying to call different API's just to play with return data but everytime I call an API I get the same error:

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'Your Site' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404

I know my call is going through because for one particular API it tracks my usage and says I have made about 5 successfull calls, so this means the data is being returned but my browser is blocking it. This only happens on Public API's. I created my own API through Azure, setup CORS, called the API, and it worked just fine. However, since I don't have access to the public servers to setup and enable CORS, there's no way for me to know how they have theirs set up.

Here's my code to call the API:

```
MyAngularApp.service('APIService', function ($http) {
    return {
        getWork: function() {
            return $.ajax({
                url: "http://api.nfldata.apiphany.com/nfl/v2/JSON/Teams/2014",
                beforeSend: function (xhrObj) {
                    // Request headers
                    xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", "*******");
                },
                type: "GET",               
            })
        .done(function (data) {
            alert("success");
        })
        .fail(function () {
            alert("error");
        });
    }
  }
});
```

Any help appreciated thanks

Comment: Yea this is a CORS issue, you can resolve it by using JSONP. By just calling the API directly you wont get a CORS issue, because you are not cross domain calling it,ie, your website `x.com` is  trying to call `p.com`, cross site.... By just putting in `p.com` into the browsers makes it a direct call.

Comment: @ppumkin I tried jsonp but I was confused on the call back aspect of jsonp. It never runs the callback function, it just tells me unexpected symbol **:**, thanks I will look more into it

Comment: Yea JSONP is a bit of a pain. Use `fiddler` to see what data is coming back in the response. I suspect your syntax in JS is incorrect. Maybe you forgot to enclose the response in `'string'` quotes, before parsing toJSON or something. That is the usual issue with unexpected symbol errors. Or maybe you DONT need to parse the response, since its already JSON Object and you can just assign it to a internal variable.

Comment: Thanks just downloaded fiddler hopefully this gives me some answers

Answer (score 0):

using jsonp is a way, but I think is better that you implemented a CORS policy to authorize the request for this domain, please read the official documentation: [Enabling Cross-Origin Requests in ASP.NET Web API 2](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api)

Comment: If I had access to their API settings I would is there anyway outside of setting up the CORS for them